# where is the .emacs files in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, mac, emacs

where is the .emacs file in Snow Leopard? I need it to configure Emacs.

Comment: A more generic but similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/73458/where-is-emacs-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

emacs will not create the config file for you. If you wish to make configurations you can create the file manually and start your configuration. You should place it in your home directory.

You could also use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize` to use emacs's inbuilt customization tool. Any changes saved in `customize` will be saved in your `.emacs` file (a new one will be created if one does't already exist).

Answer (score 5):

`C-x C-f ~/.emacs` will get you there.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in your home directory (`~/.emacs`).

If it doesn't exist, you can create it.

To create the tilde (`~`), press Option+n followed by a space.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, just create it.

Comment: Yep, if one isn't already there you can make one.

Comment: another problem. i have a mac keyboard and there is no ~ sign??

Comment: You can use Alt+n to make a tilde or simply use `cd` to get to your home directory, then make the .emacs file.

Comment: alt + n produces ñ on a mac

Comment: and find / -type -f -name ".emacs" doesnt work on a mac

Comment: Whoops, I had an extra dash in there `-f`, I've fixed the answer. If one doesn't exist in your home directory however, I'd create it instead of fiddling with find. Do not press Option+n then another n, simply pressing option+n then space will yield a `~`.

Comment: This Option+n and another n doesn't work on my Snow Leapard. Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: option+n then space. I'm not using OSX.