# Can't find .emacs file on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, emacs

I have installed emacs, specifically GNU Emacs `23.1.50.1` for Windows x86.
After installation, I can't find .emacs file. I have the .eamcs.d folder which contains other customization files that will be loaded by .emacs file.

Can you please give me a hint where it could be present.
It is not in `~/` location.

I believe it is possible for the .emacs file to not exist. In such a case, where can I create this file on my own if I finally have to?

(I am an emacs newbie.)

Answer (score 1):

Try `C-x C-f` and enter `~/.emacs`. This file normally lives under `C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\<your_username>`. (Edit: fixed the directory based on comments by  kjfletch.)

Actually in your *scratch* buffer, type `(expand-file-name "~/.emacs")` and move your cursor right behind the closing parenthesis, press `C-j` or `C-x C-e` to evaluate it. The result is the full path for your .emacs.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\<your_username>\Application Data\ on the XP system I use.

Answer (score 1):

My [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/109584/where-is-the-emacs-files-in-snow-leopard/109609#109609) to a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/109584/where-is-the-emacs-files-in-snow-leopard) about the same issue:

> emacs will not create the config file for you. If you wish to make
>   configurations you can create the file manually and start your
>   configuration. You should place it in your home directory.
>
> You could also use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize` to use emacs's inbuilt
>   customization tool. Any changes saved in `customize` will be saved in
>   your `.emacs` file (a new one will be created if one does't already
>   exist).

Specifically, in your case you could find the file in emacs <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> and enter `~/.emacs` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You could then run the `print working directory` command: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `pwd` <kbd>Enter</kbd> this will tell you where the file is on disk.

If you were perverse you could then run the explorer shell command to open that location: <kbd>M-!</kbd> `explorer .` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note:** <kbd>M-!</kbd> is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (on a standard english keyboard).