# Get my .emacs init files to load correctly with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, emacs

I tried to set up my .emacs init file in the locations recommended by [this website](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsWindowsDotEmacs), but both seem to be either not doing anything or warning me the location of `.emacs` there is deprecated:

```
c:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\.emacs
c:\
```

Where should I set the init files in emacs to have it working on Windows 7?

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/73458/where-is-emacs-file) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the best way is from a previous question: execute `M-x customize` and check where is the customization saved. In my computer, it turns out the directory is:

```
c:/Users/myusername/AppData/Roaming/.emacs
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution outside of customize is to define your `%HOME%` environment variable to point to a folder that is not obfuscated far deep in the local user "roaming" files.

- windows key + pause / advanced system settings / Environment variables:
- add a new variable for the current user
- name it `HOME`
- set its value to a folder (existing, e.g. `c:\seki`), that will be mapped to the `~` directory where Emacs puts its files by default, e.g. `~/.emacs`